# Azure DevOps - REST: how to request on backlog

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

need help on how to GET on dev azure backlog section, im able to get for the workitems/queries but unsuccessful if im requesting on backlog

This is the url to which the backlog list are located:
https://dev.azure.com/companyname/projectname/_backlogs/backlog/Project/Features

tried to follow this steps but response 400:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogs/get-backlog?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Rest API to get backlogs: [Backlogs - Get Backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogs/get-backlog?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), you need to input the valid parameter **ID** in URL.

I suggest that you can use the Rest API: to list all IDs: [Backlogs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/backlogs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

In the Response, you can get the valid ID.

For example:

[image]

You can also use the Rest API: [Backlogs - Get Backlog Level Work Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogs/get-backlog-level-work-items?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the work items corresponding to the backlog level

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/backlogs/{backlogId}/workItems?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```